# How do I hide a calculated field while hovering

Tags: tableau-api

The size of the boxes associated with my Tree Map are determined by a calculated field Sum([Total Employees]) * Min([Utilization %]). The product of the equation is not relevant and I would like to hide it but this is the only way I know how to set the ratio sizes of my boxes.

[image: Tree Map]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just click on the Tooltip button in the Marks shelf, and remove the line with the calculated field. When you add a field to the shelf, it automatically gets added to the tooltip most of the time.

[image]